# Denied US visa twice

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas

I have applied for us visa 2nd time, and it has been rejected again. The first time was in 2015. I applied without any plan and without any tentative schedule, and this time I have applied with proper channels. I plan to go to us for 7 days as a head of the delegation of team India to participate in international aerobic championship and attached invite from the US consulate, invite from us aerobics association, NOC from my employer, covering letter from Indian aerobic association, etc... They ask me why you are going now as aerobics is very popular and you should have visited other countries earlier why USA only. Then they asked why US consulate have invited you. I answer as we associated with American aerobics association. And they rejected my visa.

I want to know the basic reason of rejection, as it was a trip to participate in international sports competition.

Comment: They didn’t think your visit premise was credible. Do you have any other travel history apart from trying to visit the US?

Comment: The part of your application which doesn't make much sense to me is "invite from the US consulate". The US has many, many consulates in different countries - often more than one in a country, and although I'm not saying it's not possible, I've never head of one of them issuing an invitation. But assuming it is legitimate, did you interview at the same consulate which allegedly issued you the invitation?

Comment: What was the reason for visa refusal? All US visa refusals cite a section of US law. Which was this in your case?

Answer (score 2):

They didn't believe that you plan to leave the US at the end of the event you're planning to take part in, probably.

This may be triggered by your earlier refused entry making them extra cautious, or by a recent high number of overstays from people from your part of the world for example.

But the only people who can answer for certain are those who handled your visa application, best contact them and ask what more information they'd need for them to reconsider their refusal.

Comment: The OP was almost certainly told the reasons as part of the refusal, and they are unlikely to give any other reasons.